# Sql Server em C# utilizando BindingSource

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estou em um projeto onde tenho uma tela de venda. Ao realizar uma venda, um método verifica se o cliente tem uma conta. Se ele não tiver, ele cria uma pra ele, até aí tudo certo. Mas se o cliente já possuir essa conta, ele precisa alterar os dados apenas. Mas quando vou alterar os dados usando `BindingSource`, ele altera pelo `DataGridView` e está alterando o primeiro registro apenas.

Preciso de um filtro que pegue o nome do cliente a ser alterado, e automaticamente ele me coloque na linha do datagridview desse cliente que já vai estar cadastrado. Tentei isso mas não deu certo.

```
String searchValue = txtNome.Text;

int rowIndex = -1;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvFicha.Rows)
{
  if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
  {
     rowIndex = row.Index;
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pode fornecer mais detalhes?

Comment: Você precisa atualizar automaticamente os dados do cliente após salvar uma nova venda com um cliente existente? Se puder fornecer mais dados seria bom.

Comment: Olá, sim preciso porque quando feita uma nova venda preciso alterar o débito do cliente na conta dele. Mas ja consegui resolver o problema. Vou postar o código pra ver como eu fiz.

Comment: Olá eu ja resolvi o problema, consegui colocar um codigo que verifica se o cliente que esta na venda e o mesmo do datagridview, se nao for ele pula pro proximo registro, ai quando a condiçao for satisfeita ele para e grava no banco as informaçoes.

Comment: while (txtNomeVerificar.Text != txtNome.Text)
                {
                    this.fichaBindingSource.MoveNext();
                    txtNomeVerificar.Text = dgvFicha.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                }